# JWT Authorisation through multiple microservices

Tags: jwt, authorization, microservices, auth0

**The question in short**

What would be the correct way to handle JWT authentication for a user
who is accessing data from microservice A but where microservice A requires data from Microservice B.

**The Setup**

I am using Auth0 to issue and handle authentication and authorisation.

I have two microservices set up. The user is logged in on the front end and needs to load tenant-based accounting information.

Microservice A is an aggregate service that communicates to multiple different services in order to provide a standardized response for different types of data types.

Microservice B is queried by Microservice A in order to retrieve vehicle information owned by the user.

**Which solution would be the correct approach?**

**Solution A:**
The token that was issued to the user when he logged in will be used by MS A to communicate with MS B. MS A is essentially forwarding the token provided by the user.

**Solution B:**
MS A has its own JWT which has super admin rights to access any resource from MS B. MS A will use this token when accessing resources from MS B and MS A will take responsibility for ensuring that resources not accessible to the user are not returned in the aggregated dataset.

Answer (score 2):

In solution B you put a lot of responsibility on MS A to properly handle the data. In my opinion it's just asking for trouble, eventually someone will manage to call MS A in such a way to get some more data than they can access. So I would go with solution A, or a variant of it. There are a couple ways how tokens can be shared between services - passing the same token, embedding tokens or exchanging tokens. I have written an article about [Token Sharing](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-sharing/) a while back, you can have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends - both options are OK depending on the scenario.

Here are a few things to consider.

- Does microservice B do any resource owner authorization e.g. using the `sub` claim from the users JWT? If so it might be easier to just pass through the user access token. *Note: generally I only use data inferred from the JWT for authZ logic. If you need something like the resource owner ID as part of the business logic, you should explicitly include this in the request payload, so that the service can also be consumed by back-end services using M2M tokens.*
- With Auth0, there's a cost for machine MUAs (monthly unique authentications). This is separate to the cost for user MUAs. For an enterprise account the default is 1000 M2M MUAs. Increasing this number is pretty cheap, but still something to consider. In general you should configure your M2M tokens to have a longer expiration (e.g. 1-2 days) and use token caching. Generally an in-memory cache will suffice, but if you're building serverless apps (e.g. AWS Lambda, Azure Function Apps, etc) you'll probably need a distributed cache. All this is extra work, complexity, and potentially cost (e.g. for distributed cache) for M2M tokens.
- There's additional network request (to Auth0) for M2M authentications. This is mitigated through the use of token caching, but something to consider as well.
- Is microservice B going to be publicly accessible? If yes, you may have some security considerations as users will be able to call microservice B directly with their access tokens (obtained legitimately), but they might be able to tamper with requests in ways you weren't intending.

The company that I work for use a mix of the 2 approaches you mentioned (which generally depend on the scenario). We have some helper utils for things like token caching etc., which make both approaches easy enough, but if you're going to use M2M tokens you'll probably have a bit of additional work up-front.

One last thing to mention; when implementing 'transitive' services like microservice B, I think it's good to ensure the service is consumable by both user and machine tokens. You're authZ policies might allow for one or the other (or both), but at least you'll have the flexibility to change if/when needed.